# python given a list of dictionaries, calculate the rank of that dictionary using a specific field

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

given a list of dictionaries with all the same format and fields, calculate the rank of the dictionary based on a field. In the example below, I want to print the age ranking of each person

Ex:

```
dicts = [
    {
        'name': 'John',
        'age': 23
    },
    {
        'name': 'Sue',
        'age': 29
    },
    ...
]
for person in dicts:
    age_rank = ...
    print(f"{person['name']} is age-rank {age_rank}")
```

The oldest person should be rank 1, the next highest is rank 2, etc.

Edit: is there any way to keep the for loop untouched?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your values sorted by age descending, then combine with `enumerate` to generate the iteration index

```
for rank, person in enumerate(sorted(dicts, key=lambda x: x['age'], reverse=True), start=1):
    print(f"{person['name']} is age-rank {rank}")
```

---

Keep initial order

```
ranks = {person['name']: rank for rank, person
         in enumerate(sorted(dicts, key=lambda x: x['age'], reverse=True), start=1)}

for person in dicts:
    age_rank = ranks[person['name']]
    print(f"{person['name']} is age-rank {age_rank}")
```

Comment: is there any way to create a solution without modifying the for-loop? i.e. keep `for person in dicts` untouched?

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch that would be very inefficient, as you'd need to iterate on the whole list again for each one to find their rank

Comment: Unfortunately, I am constrained to this because I am doing many calculations for each row (dict) in the list, and this is not the only calculation that I need

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch that solution doesn't restreint you to do other calculation, I don't understand the problem, that just changes the iteration order

Comment: I can elaborate: 1. the efficiency of the code doesn't justify the drop in code quality and understanding. Upon return, I would have to remember what that piece of code does, and this problem is not important enough to justify changing the entire order of the dictionaries. 2. I need to process the dictionaries in the exact order the come in, as I need to create a dataframe in a certain order, because the shape of the dataframe and the rows are not standard at all.

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch are the names unique ?

Comment: yes, but there are 100+ columns and some of the other string and int columns need to be in certain orders as well

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch see my edit proposition

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do after but maybe using `Pandas` could be a good choice:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
df['age_rank'] = df['age'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
   name  age  age_rank
0  John   23         1
1   Sue   29         2
```

**Update**

> I am wanting to keep the for loop in the exact format that I've described. i.e. keep for person in dicts untouched

```
for person in dicts:
    age_rank = sum(person['age'] < x['age'] for x in dicts) + 1
    print(f"{person['name']} is age-rank {age_rank}")

# Output
John is age-rank 2
Sue is age-rank 1
```